# How can polymorphism be achieved with JDK7's invokedynamic

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism, java-7

Assume that I am implementing a dynamically typed language on top the JVM 7, which supports the `invokedynamic` instruction to link methods at runtime.

The dynamically typed language has a function `add` that works on integers by adding them and on strings by concatenating them. Now assume that `add` is called by a, say, generic list processing method that only knows (at compile-time) that it holds objects, either integers or strings or both.

How can `invokedynamic` help me here when compiling the the method to JVM bytecode as it has to dispatch to two different internal functions, namely the actual function that adds integers and the actual function that concatenates strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `invokedynamic` lets you invoke a method with a given signature without knowledge of the class the method belongs to. If your `add()` method just takes an `Object` (or other common base type) as an argument, then you can have `add(Object)` methods in many otherwise unrelated classes, and `invokedynamic` will be able to invoke them. As long as the target object has the method, it will be called.

Comment: I think I understand what you are telling me. This means that my dynamical call site will have to return a generic method handle that looks up the right adder (depending on the type of the arguments) and calls it, doesn't it?

Comment: If that's the way you want to go, I guess that's right. If you give `invokedynamic` an object and a method signature, it'll call the method on that object. If you want to do some searching of your own to determine the appropriate signature before the `invokedynamic`, you can certainly do that.

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at these related articles:

- [*Dynamic Language Support on the Java Virtual Machine*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-may/o30java-099612.html)
- [*Dynamically Typed Languages and the invokedynamic Instruction*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamagazine/index-404824.html)

Answer (score 0):

During my research I have also found the following link, which I would like to share:

[JSR 292 Cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/jsr292-cookbook/)

It is a collection of source code showing how to use JSR 292 to implement usual patterns that you can find in dynamic language runtimes. (Description copied from their page.)